# c++: Template variables outside the class

Tags: c++, templates

what is this concept called as:

```
typename T::size_type Length
```

I am not able to understand what's going in this line.
Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Comment: can u please help me with the line of code i have posted coz i am not getting it

Comment: In a declaration or a definition of a template, including alias template, a name that is not a member of the current instantiation and is dependent on a template parameter is not considered to be a type unless the keyword typename is used or unless it was already established as a type name, e.g. with a typedef declaration or by being used to name a base class.

Answer (score 3):

By adding `typename` before `T::size_type`, C++ will treat `size_type` as a type, rather than a static member in `T`. This is required when you use type members of a template parameter.

Therefore, this line just defines a variable `Length` with type `T::size_type`.